# Foursquare api in iPhone, Add friends from twitter and Facebook , Can anyone Explain this Function?

Tags: iphone, ios, foursquare

I am using Foursquare API .

For this , I want to add my friends who are in twitter / Facebook in Foursquare .

I got a function in its API's Sample of iPhone.

```
 +(void)searchUserPhone:(NSArray*)phones
             email:(NSArray*)emails
           twitter:(NSArray*)twitters
     twitterSource:(NSString*)twitterSource
       facebookIDs:(NSArray*)bdids
              name:(NSString*)name
          callback:(Foursquare2Callback)callback;
```

can anyone tell me how to use this function ? If possible can anyone make me a sample request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the foursquare API endpoint documentation for the /users/search endpoint: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search